# what does $ mean in the a[href$=fgh.html] selector

Tags: jquery

```
 a[href$=fgh.html]
```

what does the $ mean in here.
 Is there a way to know more about the symbols?

Comment: It's a regex style, $ means "end of string".  So that matches the `href` attribute at the end of it, for whatever is after the equals, in that case `fgh.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) jQuery selector, so it matches all `href`s that ends with `fgh.html`.

For more info about the possible selectors see:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3):

It means "an `<a>` href attribute that ends with *fgh.html*". You can find a [complete CSS3 selectors reference here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Answer (score 0):

it means `a` tag's href end with `fhg.html` word.

It selects elements that have the specified attribute (here, `href`) with a value (here, `fgh.html`) ending exactly with a given string and also case-sensitive.

[here is more](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

That'll have the Ends With selector you posted, as well as all the other ones.